# React Hooks & Typescript - Forms not controlled?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying out Hooks and Typescript for the first time after having spent months using class components.

I'm trying to setup a search bar, and I can't for some reason get it to be a controlled controlled form.

I can't also set initial state as an empty string '' with useState.

event.target.value also returns an error of "Argument type string is not assignable to parameter of type.

I did go over other posts but I can't seem to get the forms controlled and the other issues resolved. Below are my code. I'd appreciate any input I could get.

```
import React, { FC, ChangeEvent, useState } from 'react';

interface SearchQueries {
  searchTerm: string;
}

const Search: FC<SearchQueries> = () => {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState<{
    searchTerm: string;
  }>(''); **<-- Argument type of string is not assignable**

  const updateSearchTerm = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setSearchTerm(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="Enter cocktail name"
      // value={searchTerm} <-- tried commenting out to test if it's controlled (it's not)
      onChange={updateSearchTerm}
    />
  );
};

export default Search;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need for the input value is a string, so that's what you should use for the `useState` type parameter - or, even better, leave off the type parameter entirely and let TS infer it (inferring is usually preferable, since it requires less code and results in fewer mistakes like this one):

```
const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');
```

This will also result in `setSearchTerm(event.target.value);` working too.

If you wanted to pass down props and use them as the initial state (as your `FC<SearchQueries>` seems to indicate), then you need to declare the props in the argument list and use them:

```
const Search: FC<SearchQueries> = ({ searchTerm: initialSearchTerm }) => {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState(initialSearchTerm);
```

Comment: Thank you. I do have a follow up question. If I comment out the `value` attribute inside the input tag, I can still type inside the input field, but I'm not getting an uncontrolled error. I think if this were a class component, I would get an error from React about the form being uncontrolled if I don't assign a value to a state. Just worried that my implementation is still uncontrolled, even though I'm not getting any errors.

Comment: Without a `value`, the input will be uncontrolled. The existence of the `onChange` prop without an associated `value` isn't a problem in itself. (though it's admittedly weird)